# Clear selected value in UltraOptionSet

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I have an UltraOptionSet control that is unbound. Once a value has been selected, how can I clear the selected value? I want the net effect of all options in the UltraOptionSet control to be unselected.

I tried setting the Value property to null and DBNull.Value but neither cleared the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set

```
optionSet.CheckedIndex = -1;
```

this will clear the current checked item and nothing else will be set.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Value to Null rather than DBNull.Value and it will clear the selection.  You can also set the value to an empty string.

There are a few other ways as well and I believe this is all of the possible ways to clear the value for an unbound UltraOptionSet:

```
this.ultraOptionSet1.Value = null;
this.ultraOptionSet1.Value = "";
this.ultraOptionSet1.CheckedIndex = -1;
this.ultraOptionSet1.CheckedItem = null;
this.ultraOptionSet1.ResetCheckedIndex();
```

Comment: Not working for me. Stepping through code, I see .Value is true, assignment of .Value to null and then .Value is false instead of null.

Comment: Are you looking at the Value of the UltraOptionSet?  If so, can you provide the properties that you have set on the control as well as the properties that you have set on each ValueListItem in the Items collection.

Comment: Well, I created a test screen with a single UltraOptionSet control and tested .CheckedIndex = -1, .Value = null and .ResetCheckedIndex() - all succeeded and cleared the radio buttons. My other screen must have something else at play where I'm not seeing the same results.